# Can I pass a context variable into a Django form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I can't really seem to find the answer anywhere.

Basically, I have data in my view coming from an API that I want to pass into form fields. Is that possible?

Comment: Context variables are created in views and passed to the template from the views. Why would you want to pass context variable to forms?

Comment: I have data from an API coming from my view to my template and I want to send it to my db via a form. I just wanted to see it first.

Comment: This is how I would approach. If data comes from an API to my view and I have a model then I will parse the data and maybe do some inspection if needed and then save the data in my Database. Then I will have another view which will be like a ListView which will render all the data from my model in a template. I think that's an easier approach.

Comment: But yes you can pass request data from a template form to django forms. You can have a look at Modelforms or the normal django forms and wire them into your views.

Comment: I have been looking at the different kind of forms and I seen how to do "initial" values which doesn't work for me but for instance, with Flask and a regular Bootstrap form I can just do {{ value }} into the input fields and data will be sent through. How do I do that with a Django form?

Comment: That is possible. That's what happens in a UpdateView. Data rendered in the template form has an initial value. For that, you have to save the data first in the model and then have a ModelForm. Then you can create a UpdateView where you can wire up your modelform which will automatically populate your template form with initial values like you want at runtime.

Comment: @RyanThomas, please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).